# How to scan if Mac is in background / foreground

Tags: objective-c, background-foreground

Is there any posible way to know if a Mac is in background or foreground?

In iOS we have the following methods:
applicationWillEnterForeground
applicationWillenterBackground

But is there any way to know if a Mac is active or inactive?

Comment: If anyone is looking to do this in `SwiftUI` land: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72177271/1060955

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your application layout, but in general use an [`NSApplication` delegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/NSApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) and implement:

```
- (void)applicationWillBecomeActive:(NSNotification *)aNotification
```

as well as its counterpart

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(NSNotification *)aNotification
```

There are other notifications as well. See the linked document above. Also note that OS X allows real multitasking and thus background/foreground usually refer to having focus or not having focus.