# Not receiving scenePhase changes

Tags: swiftui

I'm trying to execute some code I'd have previously put in my app delegate, such as saving my managed object context when entering the background. I put the call in the `.onChange` for the scenePhase, but I'm not getting anything.

Here's a sample project:

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct PhaseApp: App {
    @Environment(\.scenePhase) private var scenePhase
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            Text("Hello, world.")
        }
        .onChange(of: scenePhase) { phase in
            switch phase {
            case .active:
                print("Active")
            case .background:
                print("Background")
            case .inactive:
                print("Inactive")
            @unknown default: break
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'd expect to get a print output in the Simulator or on my test device whenever I press Home or tap the app, but nothing happens.

Comment: The answer by @Asperi does work. But there's documentation in the Scene extension has an example where onChange operator is called on the WindowGroup. So, I think this is a bug.

Comment: This still seems to be the case in iOS 14.7. :(

Comment: Aswath is right this is a bug. @Asperi's answer works if you only require knowing the scenePhase of individual scenes. However if you require knowing about the scenePhase of the whole app, then it's incorrect.

Comment: Not sure but none of the answers on this page seems to work for me - they work on a separate test app but not in a "current production app". I am suspecting that things just won't work because we're mostly using UIHostingController for the SwiftUI parts.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use inside scene root view (usually `ContentView`)

Tested with Xcode 12 / iOS 14 as worked.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.scenePhase) private var scenePhase
    var body: some View {
        TestView()
            .onChange(of: scenePhase) { phase in
                switch phase {
                    case .active:
                        print(">> your code is here on scene become active")
                    case .inactive:
                        print(">> your code is here on scene become inactive")
                    case .background:
                        print(">> your code is here on scene go background")
                    default:
                        print(">> do something else in future")
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI this answer is slightly misleading as it doesn't provide the same outcome as what's expected of the poster's code. The poster's code will tell you about scenePhase changes about the WHOLE app. @Asperi's answer will only tell you about scenePhase changes of the current scene. 
Use this answer with caution and hopefully Apple fix the bug on WindowGroup.

Comment: thank solved to my issue

Answer (score 31):

I acknowledge this question is specifically about `schenePhase` changes, however, on macOS I am not able to receive any `.background` notifications when a user switches to a different app. The older `NotificationCenter` strategy works as I expected, on both platforms. I'll add this to the mix for anyone who is just trying to execute some code, `onForeground` / `onBackground` on `iOS` and `macOS`.

On any view, you can attach:

```swift
.onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: .willResignActiveNotification)) { _ in
    doBackgroundThing()
}
```

The events you may care about are:

- iOS: [`willResignActiveNotification`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1622973-willresignactivenotification) & [`willEnterForegroundNotification`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1622944-willenterforegroundnotification)
- macOS: [`willResignActiveNotification`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsapplication/1428356-willresignactivenotification) & [`willBecomeActiveNotification`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsapplication/1428383-willbecomeactivenotification)

You can find all `NotificationCenter` `Name`s [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsnotification/name).

I use `will*` variants for background because I assume they'll be called early in the process, and I use `did*` variants for foreground, because they are called regardless of whether the app is launched for the first time, or it's coming out of background.

I use this extension so I don't have to think about the platform differences:

```swift
extension View {
    #if os(iOS)
    func onBackground(_ f: @escaping () -> Void) -> some View {
        self.onReceive(
            NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIApplication.willResignActiveNotification),
            perform: { _ in f() }
        )
    }
    
    func onForeground(_ f: @escaping () -> Void) -> some View {
        self.onReceive(
            NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification),
            perform: { _ in f() }
        )
    }
    #else
    func onBackground(_ f: @escaping () -> Void) -> some View {
        self.onReceive(
            NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: NSApplication.willResignActiveNotification),
            perform: { _ in f() }
        )
    }
    
    func onForeground(_ f: @escaping () -> Void) -> some View {
        self.onReceive(
            NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: NSApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification),
            perform: { _ in f() }
        )
    }
    #endif
}
```

As expected, I use it as such:

```swift
AppView()
   .onBackground {
       print("my background")
   }
   .onForeground {
       print("my foreground")
   }
```

Comment: On macOS I don't receive ANY ScenePhase changes with `.onChange(of:)` – no matter if on scene or view. Very strange since every documentation says it should do so.   Your answer solved my issue.

Comment: @ChrisR I was only able to receive `.inactive` if I bind to my root view, and hit the yellow `-` button.

Perhaps when you're low on system resources we'd see other states too?

Comment: This rocks - thank you!

Comment: Just figured out that in macOS this doesn't work if the user closes the window and opens it again. ie, this works only if the user switches to another app without closing the window.

Comment: FYI, When a window is opened after being closed manually, `onAppear` is called.

Answer (score 7):

I've been testing with Xcode 12 beta 3 and iOS/iPadOS 14 beta 3 and here's what I'm finding. Note that a lot of this involves supporting multiple windows, but the "SwiftUI lifecycle" projects *default* to turning that on, so I suspect you have it active already. In my original case I was porting an existing SwiftUI app from a `SceneDelegate` to using the new `App` struct, so I had multiple window support already active.

Here's the test `View` I'm using in a new testing app:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.scenePhase) private var scenePhase

    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, world!").padding()
            .onChange(of: scenePhase) { phase in
                switch phase {
                case .background:
                    print("PHASECHANGE: View entered background")
                case .active:
                    print("PHASECHANGE: View entered active")
                case .inactive:
                    print("PHASECHANGE: View entered inactive")
                @unknown default:
                    print("PHASECHANGE: View entered unknown phase.")
                }
            }
    }
}
```

(I have identical code in the `App` & `Scene` but they never print anything.)

1. The [ScenePhase documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/scenephase) claims that you can declare `onChange` inside the `App`, a `Scene` *or* a `View`. I don't see the `App` or `Scene` level versions ever execute, under any circumstance I can engineer, and the `View` level versions don't seem to execute completely correctly.
2. <del>On hardware that *doesn't* support multiple windows (I use a 7th generation iPod touch) the `View` level closure executes *every* time. (Full disclosure, this iPod Touch is still running beta 2, but I don't think it's going to matter. Once I update it to b3 I'll mention it here if it matters.)</del> **EDIT** (It did matter.)
   On hardware running beta 2 that doesn't support multiple windows (a 7th generation iPod Touch) I see the app go into the background, back into the foreground, and so forth. On every app launch I'll see "View entered active" print.
3. On hardware that *does* support multiple windows (I use an older iPad Pro with the Lightning connector) I don't see the initial scene creation happen. (The first run does *not* trigger a "View entered active" message.) I do see subsequent background/foreground transitions. If I create a new scene from the iPad multi-tasking UI the *second* scene will trigger a "View entered active" log. Unfortunately I hadn't run this test on the iPad against beta 2, so I can't say if the behavior changed with b3 or not.
4. On my iPod Touch running iOS 14 beta 3 I see the same behavior as the iPad: the first launch doesn't print any phase change messages from the view, but does report subsequent background/foreground changes.
5. On the simulator it always behaves like the iPad hardware, even when I'm simulating an iPod Touch. I suspect this is because the simulator is running under the hood on the Mac and gets multiple window "support" this way. But I do see messages when I put the app in the background while running in the simulator, I'm just missing the initial "View entered active" message that I get from the actual hardware.

One final note: when I return an app from the foreground I *first* see "View entered inactive" and then I see "View entered active". When I background the app I see "View entered inactive", followed by "View entered background". I think this is expected behavior, but since other parts seem broken I wanted to mention it.

---

TL;DR:

I think you should be able to see *most* `ScenePhase` changes from a `View`, but you'll miss the initial app launch <del>on iPads or in the simulator</del>. And hopefully they will show up as expected for `App` and `Scene` objects in a later beta?

Comment: Additional observations (Xcode 13.4.1 (13F100), iOS 15.x):
In a multi window setup, SwiftUI Lifecycle with App- and SceneDelegates, the base functionality for scenePhase changes in Views seem to work, but only when there are no more than 2 windows open. When more will be opened, then the scenePhase changes will not be delivered to the View.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I put "@Environment(.scenePhase) private var scenePhase" in ContentView. Then the onChange works in the child views.

Comment: Please read my comment on @Timothy Sanders answer. There's a catch! 
My observation is, that a View does not receive any scenePhase changes anymore when there have been more  than two UIScenes created  for this view.

Comment: I confirm the "scenePhase" still doesn't work on iOS when we have more than two scenes, which makes it useless for multi-scene iOS apps... Tested on iOS 17.2 beta.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following extension:

```
public extension View {
    func onScenePhaseChange(phase: ScenePhase, action: @escaping () -> ()) -> some View {
        self.modifier(OnScenePhaseChangeModifier(phase: phase, action: action))
    }
}

public struct OnScenePhaseChangeModifier: ViewModifier {
    @Environment(\.scenePhase) private var scenePhase
    
    public let phase: ScenePhase
    
    public let action: () -> ()
    
    public func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .onChange(of: scenePhase) { phase in
                if (self.phase == phase) {
                    action()
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Final usage:

```
ContentView()
     .onScenePhaseChange(phase: .active)     { print("scene activated!") }
     .onScenePhaseChange(phase: .background) { print("scene backgrounded!") }
     .onScenePhaseChange(phase: .inactive)   { print("scene inactive!") }
```

Comment: If I use it like this all states are triggered! Just in the order you write them in the code. I guess if (phase == phase) might be the problem. I renamed one and it works much better.

Comment: `code`
public struct OnScenePhaseChangeModifier: ViewModifier {
    @Environment(\.scenePhase) private var scenePhase
    public let phase: ScenePhase
    public let action: () -> ()
    public func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .onChange(of: scenePhase) { newphase in
                if (phase == newphase) {
                    action()
                }
            }
    }
}
`code`

Answer (score 2):

the modifiers available with the new Concurrency are much stable than `onChange`

```
    .task(id: scenePhase) { 
        switch scenePhase {
        case .active:
            print("Active")
        case .background:
            print("Background")
        case .inactive:
            print("Inactive")
        @unknown default: break
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I experimented with the environment values `scenePhase`, `controlActiveState`, with `onAppear`, `onDisappear` and @Parth Mehrotra's [`NotificationCenter` approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72177271/16157878). The thing is, nothing does reliably publish the activity state of the app, i.e. so that it reflects `NSApp.isActive`. It should also work when the app has no or many windows, which lead me to the conclusion that attaching the code to a view is not right.

Considering it is also not recommended to [conform AppDelegate to `ObservableObject`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62998695/how-to-confirm-observableobject-for-an-appdelegate), I made this observable class:

```swift
#if os(iOS)
import UIKit
#else
import AppKit
#endif

class AppState: NSObject, ObservableObject {
    @Published var activity: Activity = .inactive
    private var appMonitor: [NSObjectProtocol] = []
    
    enum Activity {
        case active
        case inactive
    }
    
    override init() {
        super.init()
#if os(iOS)
        appMonitor.append(NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: UIApplication.willResignActiveNotification, object: nil, queue: nil) { notification in
            self.activity = .inactive
        })
        appMonitor.append(NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification, object: nil, queue: nil) { notification in
            self.activity = .active
        })
#else
        appMonitor.append(NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NSApplication.willResignActiveNotification, object: nil, queue: nil) { notification in
            self.activity = .inactive
        })
        appMonitor.append(NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NSApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification, object: nil, queue: nil) { notification in
            self.activity = .active
        })
#endif
    }
}
```

It can be used like this:

```swift
import SwiftUI

@main
struct ActiveStateApp: App {
    @Environment(\.scenePhase) private var scenePhase
    @StateObject var app = AppState()
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        } 
        .onChange(of: app.activity) { state in
            print("AppState: \(state), NSApp.isActive: \(NSApp.isActive)")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a heads up if you are trying to detect scene changes in a veiw presented in with a `.sheet` modifier. In this case you have to pass the environment of the presenting view down to the sheet view in order to get scenePhase updates:

```
struct YourView: View {
    @Environment (\.scenePhase) private var scenePhase
    var body: some View {
        Text("Some Text")
            .sheet(isPresented: .constant(true)) {
                YourSheetView()
                  .environment(\.scenePhase, scenePhase)
            }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps someone!