# How to check if an app enters background on Apple watch when using SwiftUI

Tags: swift, background, swiftui, watchkit, watchos

I know for an iOS app, you can use something like

```
Text("Hello, World!")
    .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIApplication.willResignActiveNotification)) { _ in
        print("Moving to the background!")}
```

But I can not use willResignActiveNotification for WatchOS.
What should I do to detect if my watchOS app enters the background?

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/62840614/12299030?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `WKExtensionDelegate` methods to monitor WatchKit app lifecycle events. There is no notification fired on these events, so you need to implement the `applicationWillResignActive` delegate method instead. You can publish a custom notification from there and make your `View` listen to those notifications or simply create a custom `Publisher` that emits a value on `WKExtensionDelegate` method calls.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am using SwiftUI lifecycle now. This link stackoverflow.com/a/62840614/12299030 recommended by @Asperi solved my problem.