# How to call function when app regains focus?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

My user is redirected to their inbox when they verify their email. When they reopen the application I need to reload the user's data automatically. I used the following code to do so...

```
.onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification)) { _ in
        
        Auth.auth().currentUser?.reload()

    }
```

However, this code only works if I completely close the application and reopen it. Is there a way for me to call this without having to close the application?

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/62840614/12299030?

Comment: @Asperi No it doesn't because I am not using an environment. I need to refresh an ID token when the user verifies their email from firebase. But, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `didBecomeActiveNotification`:

```
.onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification)) { _ in
    Auth.auth().currentUser?.reload()
}
```

Comment: It does the same as the example I provided above

Comment: @EmirElAli I'm not sure I understand your problem. The above code will run every time your app *becomes active* even if it wasn't in the background. What exactly is your issue?

Comment: In my app, the user presses a button that sends them and email verification link. They exit my app, enter their email inbox and press the link to verify their email. When they re-enter my app i need to run the following code “Auth.auth().currentUser?.reload()”. So far with the code i provided above it does not run the code when they re-enter the application. It only runs if the user fully quits the application and re-opens it.

Comment: @EmirElAli It works for me, Xcode 12.3, iOS 14.3. Did you try `print` as well? Maybe the problem is in `Auth.auth().currentUser?.reload()`.

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different approach but should do the same,

In ViewDidAppear:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(yourFunction), name: UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification, object: nil)

@objc function yourFunction(){
  print("Returned from background")
  // Do something
}
```