# SwiftUI: way to check that WINDOW(not app) activated (become foreground)

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I need to call some method on event when my app become foreground

(I'm using ViewModel for each view, so I can call sth not only from view)

As example:

1. my app is runned;
2. changed foreground window to Safari app.
3. Changed foreground window to my app -> some method called.

With `.onChange(of: scenePhase) -> .active` nothing happens with this scenario

so those code is not solution for me:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.scenePhase) private var scenePhase
    var body: some View {
        TestView()
            .onChange(of: scenePhase) { phase in
                switch phase {
                    case .active:
                        print("App is active")
                    default:
                        break
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you asking how to receive `applicationDidBecomeActive` in the SwiftUI view lifecycle, or are you asking how to pass that notification down to your views?

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/62840614/12299030?

Comment: @Asperi  https://prnt.sc/xtl9wh Already tried. It doesn't work like I'm expected. I need to call some method on my app WINDOW activation. Updated the question

Comment: Those code works in case of my app was hiddend and after this activated. Bu I need to call method on window of my app become foreground (window is activated)

Comment: For advanced use cases, I suggest you use the DelegateAdaptor like NSApplicationDelegateAdaptor to shim a custom AppDelegate class that can get the full lifecycle event as UIKit/AppKit. Then broadcast as a Notification using notification center and receive using combine, this is easier to use in your view model than passing using the SwiftUI environment.

Comment: @zrfrank which notification I need to use for this? I see no "window become foreground" - only "app..."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Way 1:

(better)

You can use custom AppDelegate with function `applicationDidBecomeActive`

main app file:

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct FileBoApp: App {
//SOLUTION p1
    @NSApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate : AppDelegate
//END SOLUTION p1
    
    var body: some Scene {
        /// bla bla bla
    }
}
```

appDelegate file:

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

//SOLUTION p2
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ notification: Notification) {
       print("FUUUUUUUUUUUU")
    }
}
//END SOLUTION p2
```

==============================================

---

### Way 2:

( alternative )

```
    @SceneBuilder var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            SomeView()
//SOLUTION
                .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: NSApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification)) { (_) in
                          print("FUUUUUUUUUUUU")
                        }
//END SOLUTION
            
        }
```

Answer (score 7):

You could use the environment variable `controlActiveState` as follows:

```
@Environment(\.controlActiveState) var controlActiveState
```

Comment: I liked Andrew's notification approach, but this one is more flexible as it will give you an enum that can be .active, .inactive, and .key (meaning this view receives keypresses)

Comment: @MortenJ You could monitor any changes to the value by using `onChange(of: controlActiveState)`