# SwiftUI : onChange(of: scenePhase) is not firing

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I am working on a project with SwiftUI and having trouble with receiving events such as app entering foreground and background. The events are simply not firing at all. Please refer to the code below.

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct testApp: App {
    
    @Environment(\.scenePhase) private var scenePhase
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .onChange(of: scenePhase) { phase in
                    if phase == .background {
                        print("background")
                    }
                    if phase == .active {
                        print("active")
                    }
                    if phase == .inactive {
                        print("inactive")
                    }
                    
                }
        }
    }
}
```

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, world!").padding()
    }
}
```

Xcode version is 12.5 and running this on iOS 14.0 - 14.5 simulator. I tried it on iOS 15 and it worked fine. Is this some kind of a bug in iOS 14?

I am very new to developing iPhone apps. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/62840614/12299030?

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I tried almost all the solutions I could find on Stack Overflow including the link you just posted but still no luck ... Stuck on this problem all day ...

Answer (score 1):

You can use .onReceive() with notification publishers you need.