# How to pop up a view after application enter foreground?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm working on digital banking app. I need the user to be re prompted for PIN/Password after the app enter background for more than X seconds. I look up scene delegate's functions but I have no idea how can I check how long the user has been in foreground and how to popping out the view. I use AppDelegate and SceneDelegate for lifecycle

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/62840614/12299030?

Answer (score 4):

you can do this by using local notification what you have to do is following.

easy steps for new user

1. manage a global object for app state // if needed
2. add a local notification in your main view controller
3. post a notification from your SceneDelegate

here is the example

add observer in your main controller which always appears when app start or launch

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController 
{
     override func viewDidLoad() 
     {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(showPopup(notification:)), name: 
            NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "showPinCodePopup"), object: nil)
    }
    // remove observer 
    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) 
    {
          NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
    }
    @objc func showPopup(notification: NSNotification) {
    
          //show your popup here
    }
    
}
```

call the local notification from your SceneDelegate when app becomes active or enter in Foreground.

```
class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate 
{
    var window: UIWindow?
    func sceneDidBecomeActive(_ scene: UIScene) {

        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name(rawValue:"showPinCodePopup"), object: nil, userInfo:nil)
        // Called when the scene has moved from an inactive state to an active state.
        // Use this method to restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) when the scene was inactive.
    }

}
```

Hope this solution may helps you

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to mention that I use swiftUI..