# Trying to understand scene phase environment variable when used with macOS and Swiftui

Tags: swiftui, environment-variables, scene

I am trying to understand how the scene phase works with swift and macOS.  I have the test code below that works but I only get active and inactive printed.  Further, inactive is only printed if I minimize the apps window with the yellow button at the top left of the associated window.  I would have thought that when my app goes to the background, i.e. I bring Safari to the foreground for example, my app would transition from active then to inactive then to background but that does not appear to be the case.  The scene phase does not appear to change at all in this circumstance, at least nothing is printed.  If someone could provide me with a better understanding it would be appreciated.

Chris

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.scenePhase) private var scenePhase
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, world!")
            .padding()
            .frame(width: 600, height: 400, alignment: .center)
            .onChange(of: scenePhase, perform: { phase in
                switch phase {
                case .active: print("Active")
                case .background: print("Background")
                case .inactive: print("Inactive")
                default: print("Who Knows")
                }
            })
    }
}
```

Comment: macOS apps do not, like iOS apps, go to the background in any significant way in terms of how their performance or capabilities are affected. Their window just becomes inactive.

Comment: When the window is not the key window, does this change the scene phase to `inactive`?

Comment: When the program window is on the screen and selected, if I then select another window such as safari the program does not print any change in scene phase.  When I select the program window again (which I think. makes it the key window) the program does not print any change in the scene phase.

Comment: @Chris, I solved this problem on macOS [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72177271/1060955)