# How to share an object between AppDelegate and SceneDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am already using **AppDelegate** for registering with APNs, but since it does not support the *applicationWillResignActive()* and *applicationWillEnterForeground()* functions which handled by the **SceneDelegate** as explained in [here](https://www.fivestars.blog/articles/app-delegate-scene-delegate-swiftui/).

I want both delegates to have the access to my client instance. Currently, the **AppDelegate** instantiates the *client* as its property and then it is passed to the scene as an *environmentObject*:

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct app1App: App {

  @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate

  var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
      MainView().environmentObject(appDelegate.client)
    }
  }
}

class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate {
  
  let client : Client = Client()
  // other Notifications related functions
}
```

When I declare my client in views as:

```
@EnvironmentObject var client: Client
```

then the views have the access to the client's methods, however, the same approach does not work when I declare it in the SceneDelegate:

```
class SceneDelegate: NSObject, UIWindowSceneDelegate {

  @EnvironmentObject var client: Client

  func sceneWillEnterForeground(_ scene: UIScene) {
    self.client.disconnect()  // This fails in runtime!!!
  }
}
```

The error says it is expecting an observable object, but my object is environmentObject:

```
Thread 1: Fatal error: No ObservableObject of type Client found. A View.environmentObject(_:) for Client may be missing as an ancestor of this view.
```

What's the proper way to provide the access to the client by the functions from the SceneDeleagte?

Comment: Maybe you just need this https://stackoverflow.com/a/62840614/12299030? If not then SceneDelegate is possible to set up as shown here https://stackoverflow.com/a/60359809/12299030.

Comment: @Asperi almost got to the bottom of it - question updated. Just need help with sharing the client between the two delegates - any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Just need
> help with sharing the client between the two delegates - any
> suggestions?

If it is app-wide to be shared then the simplest is to make it global

```
let client : Client = Client()    // << create here

class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate {
  // access `client` here directly
  // other Notifications related functions
}

class SceneDelegate: NSObject, UIWindowSceneDelegate {

  func sceneWillEnterForeground(_ scene: UIScene) {
    // access `client` here directly
    client.disconnect()  // This fails in runtime!!!
  }
}
```

Comment: My AppDelegate and SceneDelegate are in different files. When I put `let client : Client = Client()` right below `@main` externally to `struct app1App: App {}` (as I would declare a global variable in C language), then the compiler complains saying _'@main' attribute cannot be applied to this declaration_. So, where exactly it should go in my case? Should it still be an _environmetObject_ to be accessed and monitored by views?

Comment: Placing the global definition above `@main` fixed the issue.